# How to create flutter image slider (Example flipkart product details page)

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

How can you create this method of slider?

[image]

Comment: Hi Nousath ! Welcome to SO. You have to show the community what you did and didn't work for you, preferably if you put the code snippet and outlined which part didn't work as expected, Thanks.

Comment: checkout Full screen carousel in this package with autoplay: false https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/carousel_slider else you can use viewpager too.

Comment: @izhang I've approved the edit, but you should have checked the content of the images before inlining them: they were identical